# Валидация. Проверка и вызов функции

Tags: javascript

Я хочу вызвать функцию только в том случае, если форма валидна.

Проверка корректно работает, но я не могу правильно вызвать функцию addUser(). addUser работает, но он зациклен, при следующим вызове срабатывает  2 раза, потом 5 и так далее.

И еще форма должна отправляться только в addUser(). По отдельности они работают правильно, а вместе нет.

Могут быть несколько телефонов.

```
----------
     if (lastName.value.match(letters)) {    
        for(var i = 0; i < phones.length; i++){
          if (!phones[i].value.match(digts)) {
            error.innerHTML = 'Only digits';
            frm.insertBefore(error, phones[i]);
            errorMessage = "false";
            phones[i].focus();
            if(phones[phones.length - 1].value != '') {
              addUser();
            };
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if(user.value == ''){
            //code
        }
           errorMessage = "false";
        }
          if (errorMessage !== "") {
              event.preventDefault();
          }
        }

----------

    function addUser(){
        $('#registration').submit(function(event) {
          alert(12);
           //code
          event.preventDefault();
          var data = 'phones=' + JSON.stringify(arrUserInfo);
          $.ajax({
            //code
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: это все потому, что **каждый** вызов `addUser` добавляет обработчик `submit`

Comment: И как это исправить? Не подскажите? Я не понял как он добавляет. @Grundy

Comment: вызов `$('#registration').submit(function(event) {...})` вешает обработчик, а не выполняет функцию. Это значит, что не стоит вызывать метод `addUser` несколько раз. По крайней мере в текущем виде.

Comment: то есть из за того что `addUser` в цикле, эти обработчики и вешаются? мне надо убрать в другое место проверку для `addUser`? но я пробовал и не помогает @Grundy

Comment: можешь попробовать заменить вызов addUser на `$('#registration').submit()`. Но я пока слабо представляю как связан предоставленный код и сама функция `addUser` поэтому возможно надо делать что-то еще

Comment: Я могу выложить весь код, там где то 10-20  строк плюс @Grundy

Comment: лучше сделай [mcve]

Comment: ТС, а почему не используете стандартную HTML валидацию формы, зачем это велосипедостроение?

Comment: @yar85, стандартная валидация слабо поддается кастомизации

Comment: @Grundy, я не про валидити репорт (сообщения пользователю), а про саму валидацию (проверку введенных данных) формы. ТС проверяет регулярками - эти же регулярки можно прописать в атрибутах `pattern`. Разница в том, что браузер сработает четко и безошибочно, в отличие от самописных обработчиков. Код проверки упрощается до вызова единственного метода с булевым результатом. А дальше - можно и кастомные сообщения показывать, и вообще все что  угодно городить... полная свобода действий.

Comment: ...и хотя в данном случае причина проблемы не в самой проверке - это не отменяет того что стандартная валидация удобнее и надежнее. Поэтому и спрашивал, чего бы ей изначально не воспользоваться.

Comment: @yar85, если уж на то пошло, то судя из названий - pattern Тоже не нужен, достаточно поставить `type=tel'